# Logstash - converting xml data and load into ES

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, elasticsearch-5, logstash-file

XML format data

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<details>
    <id>544538</id>
    <name>john</icUrl>
    <version>2.0.0-10</version>

    <OptionalValues>
        <metaData>
            <name>Severity</name>
            <value>Medium</value>
        </metaData>
        <metaData>
            <name>Prioriry</name>
            <value>5</value>
        </metaData>
     <OptionalValues>

    <issue>
        <summary>summary value</summary>
        <description>It is possible to misconfigure an EtherChannel and create a spanning-tree loop. This misconfiguration would potentially overwhelm the switch process. Cisco IOS System Software includes a feature called 'spanning-tree etherchannel guard misconfig' to prevent this issue.</description>
    </issue>
 </details>
```

using logstash, i need to convert like this.
id,name,version,severity,priority,summary,description .. how can i convert xml to json output. 
i tried to parse id field before going to apply all the fields.

```
input {  
    file {
        path => "C:/Users/Desktop/mydata.xml"
            start_position => "beginning"
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter {
    xml {
        source => "message"
        force_array => false
        remove_namespaces =>true   
        store_xml => true
        target => "doc"
        xpath => [  

            "details/id", "myid"
            ]
    }
}

output 
{
    stdout{
        codec => line {     
            format => "%{[myid]}"
        }
    }
}
```

while executing i am gettin empty myid value in the console. Also tell me after format into json how can i redirect into es index.

Comment: Any thought on this @Val

Answer (score 0):

Based on this

> https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp

it seems to me that your xpath is lacking a "/" at the beginning. It is not tested, so there is no guarantee.
And this shows the most basic configuration for es output:

> https://logz.io/blog/logstash-tutorial/

If you need more detailed options I suggest the logstash page with the elasticsearch output plugin.